# INSERT and UPDATE after one row inserted MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, where-clause

I don't know if I'm thinking correct, so I'm open for suggestions.
I'm using MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
Here is the 'story'
Everytime someone insert a row into tblDelivered there is a trigger that insert in tblConditionDel five values(1,1,1,1,1). This is a table with an auto ID increment. And for that inserted row must fieldname ConditionID be updated with the ID from tblConditionDel.
I think there is something wrong with my where statement
If I delete the where statement the ID is update for the entire table, but it must be for the one inserted row.

My code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCond2] ON [dbo].[tblDelivered] 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
insert into tblConditionDel(Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4, Con5)
values(1,1,1,1,1);

update tblDelivered set ConditionID = (select max(ConditionID) from tblConditionDel)
where (select 1 from inserted) = tblDelivered.ConditionID
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Select 1 from inserted will always return 1.  You need to select whatever id value you can use to identify your record.

Comment: Oh ok, I tought you would select the first column of inserted. Thx for the info ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work if more than one row is inserted.

Do like this

```
CREATE TABLE tblDelivered (
    DeliveredID int NOT NULL
   ,ConditionID int
);

CREATE TABLE tblConditionDel (
    ConditionID int IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,Con1 int NOT NULL
   ,Con2 int NOT NULL
   ,Con3 int NOT NULL
   ,Con4 int NOT NULL
   ,Con5 int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCond2] ON [dbo].[tblDelivered] 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ConditionIDs AS table ( -- stores inserted conditionsIDs
        DeliveredID int NOT NULL
       ,ConditionID int NOT NULL
    );

    MERGE INTO tblConditionDel -- INSERT does not support OUTPUT INTO for multiple rows
    USING inserted AS triggerinserted
        ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Con1, Con2, Con3, Con4, Con5)
        VALUES (1,1,1,1,1)
    OUTPUT triggerinserted.DeliveredID
          ,inserted.ConditionID
    INTO @ConditionIDs;

    UPDATE tblDelivered
    SET ConditionID = ConditionIDs.ConditionID
    FROM tblDelivered
         INNER JOIN @ConditionIDs AS ConditionIDs
             ON ConditionIDs.DeliveredID = tblDelivered.DeliveredID

-- Test code
INSERT INTO tblDelivered (DeliveredID)
VALUES (4),(5),(6);

SELECT * FROM tblConditionDel
SELECT * FROM tblDelivered
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCond2] ON [dbo].[tblDelivered] 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
declare @new_id int, @delivered_id int

set @delivered_id = (select ConditionID from inserted) -- captures id from inserted table

insert into tblConditionDel(Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4, Con5)
values(1,1,1,1,1);

set @new_id = scope_identity() -- captures new id from tblCondition into a variable

update tblDelivered set ConditionID = @new_id -- set new tblcondition id
where ConditionID = @delivered_id -- for the record that matches the inserted one
```